# CharAt gives "Cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

I recently start studying JAVA, and I find this code:

```
public class Dublicate{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int r=0;
      for(int i=0;i<(args[0]).length();i++){
         char ch=args[0].CharAt(i);
         r=r*10+ch-'0';
      }
      System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

I don't really confident that this code will work properly, I don't confident in 
`args[0]`, but this code don't what to compile:

```
Dublicate.java:6: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method CharAt(int)  
location: class java.lang.String  
            char ch=a.CharAt(i);  
                     ^  
1 error
```

**How I can solve this problem?**

P.S. Also if I write:

```
int i=4;
String a = "argsas";
char ch=a.CharAt(i);
```

I also get Error:

```
Dublicate.java:5: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method CharAt(int)  
location: class java.lang.String  
             char ch=a.CharAt(i);  
                      ^  
1 error
```

**Update:**
Yeah, lovercase works thank you all!!!

Comment: Since you study Java, it would help if you looked at the javadoc when you have such a problem (or to avoid such problems): http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. Bookmark it, and consult it each time it's necessary.

Comment: By the way, if you develop with Eclipse, it finds directly the error and change quite automatically this error to adopt the good syntax.

Comment: I decided not to use IDE for some time and  do all with my hands, text editor and terminal java compiler.

Comment: Good for you.  That's a smart choice.  You can add an IDE when you're comfortable.  My observation is that people who don't know Java and start with Eclipse or NetBeans have two problems to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "charAt" - lower case.  .NET starts method with upper case as a convention; Java uses lower case.  If you found this code somewhere, it's a bad choice.

```
public class Dublicate{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length > 0) {
           int r=0;
           for (int i = 0; i < args[0].length(); ++i) { 
                char ch=args[0].charAt(i);
                r=r*10+ch-'0';
            }
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We may also face this kind of error if the square bracket is placed in place of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You should write `charAt`, starting with a lower-case C.

See: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

It should be charAt instead of CharAt.

```
    int i=2;
    String a = "argsas";
    char ch=a.charAt(i); 
    System.out.println(ch);
```